# Kotlin - how to fix type mismatch for non null type

Tags: kotlin

I have a function that receives a value as an optional value that can be `null` or a defined `Type`.
So, for example a function like this:

```
fun myFunction(type:Type?) {}
```

The problem is that inside that function I call another function that requires Type to be of a Type and not `null`.

```
fun myFunction(type:Type?) {
   val conf = getConfFor(type)
}
```

Because of that the code won't compile. I get:

```
Type mismatch.
Required:
Type
Found:
Type?
```

I have tried to fix this by checking if the value is not null, like this:

```
if (type:Type !== null) val conf = getConfFor(type)
```

But, that didn't help.
I have also tried with using `let` function:

```
val conf = type?.let { getConfFor(type) }
```

But, then I had problems down the chain, because other calls that used conf had also required `non null` value, and now `conf` was possible `null`.
How can I avoid this error, by bypassing it for when the value is there, and not `null`, so that I avoid changing type of `non null` value for every function down the chain?

Comment: Ah, that is it! Thanks!

Comment: I wonder why the if approach didn’t work, because it should. Maybe because you used reference equality instead of structural equality? Honestly, !! seems a code smell to me and I try to avoid using it.

Comment: Forcing non null `type` with `!!` will just cause your code block to crash if it's `null` which goes against entire requirement of it being an optional value. You can either assign a default `conf` for null type, keep checking if `conf` is null or just branch out to execute entirely different code for when type is null.